# Solving linear program with matrices in CVXPY

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

I'm using CVXPY in Python 3 to try to model the following linear program in `X` (N by T matrix). Let

- `R` be an N by 1 matrix where each row is the sum of the entire row of values in `X`.
- `P` be a 1 by N matrix defined in terms of `X` such as `P_t = 1/(G-d-x_t)`.

I want to solve for an ideal such that:

> minimize (X x P)
>
> subject to:
>
> The sum of reach row i in X has to be at least the value in R_i
>
> Each value in X has to be at least 0

Any thoughts? I have the following code and not getting any luck:

```
from cvxpy import *
X = Variable(N,T)
P = np.random.randn(T, 1)

R = cumsum(X,axis=0) # using cumsum because 
http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/functions/index.html#vector-matrix-functions


objective = Minimize(sum_entries(square(X*P))) #think this is good

constraints = [0 <= X, cumsum(X,axis=0) >= R]
prob = Problem(objective, constraints)
```

Comment: what are values for N, T?

Comment: I don't understand the problem from your description. Could you write it out mathematically?

Comment: If `P` depends on `X`, why did you generate a random matrix?